# laravel cookies doesn't work after post data

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2 and i want to create REST api (simple, just login) and i have this code:

```
Route::get('/login', function() {
    dd(Cookie::get('token'));
});

Route::post('/login', function () {
    $name = Request::get('login');
    $password = Request::get('password');
    if (!empty($name) && !empty($password)) {
        $user = App\User::where('name',$name)->first();
        if ($user)
        {
            if ($user->password === sha1($user->salt . $password))
            {
                $tokenCookie = Cookie::queue('token',sha1($user->name),10);
                return Response::make()->withCookie($tokenCookie);
            } else {
                echo 'nieprawidłowe hasło';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'brak konta w bazie danych';
        }
    } else {
        return 'brak danych';
    }
});
```

and problem is cookie doesn't work. I mean after i send POST informations everything works fine (i don't have any echo so it should be fine) but when i go to /login page i have 'null' response. It looks like cookies are not set. Help?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Laravel 5.2, you need to make sure any routes that need use session information (e.g. cookies) are inside the `web` middleware group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/login', function() {
        // code
    });

    Route::post('/login', function () {
        // code
    });
});
```